# Client Login using Flutter for Mediawiki

Tags: flutter, dart, mediawiki

I am in the learning proess for both flutter and requests so forgive me if it is a simple mistake. I am trying to make a client login to a mediaiwki instance using client login api. I can fetch the login token succesfully but when I try to login it says invalid csrf token it gives {"error":{"code":"badtoken","info":"Invalid CSRF token.","*":". The api I am using to login is as follows.
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Method_2._clientlogin
Thanks for your help.

To fetch login token succesfully I use

```
_fetch_login_token() async {
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  Map<String, String> body = {
    'action': "query",
    'meta': "tokens",
    'type': "login",
    'format': "json"
  };

  Response response = await post(
    url,
    body: body,
  );
  //print(response);
  // int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  // print(statusCode);
  var decoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(decoded);
  var jsonsData = response.body; // toString of Response's body is assigned to jsonDataString
  var data = jsonDecode(jsonsData);
  var token=data['query']['tokens']['logintoken'];
  return _makePostRequest(token);
}
```

And  my failed login as follows

```
Map<String, String> body = {
    'action': "clientlogin",
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'loginreturnurl': url,
    'logintoken': loginToken,
    'format': "json"
    };

  Response response = await post(
    url,
    body:body,
  );
```

Comment: Did you check the return json you get back, just to make sure 1) You are getting the token 2) Your token field is pointing to the right json key.  Try posting the return json data.  It should help.

Comment: Hello. I am getting the following response from fetch login key. {batchcomplete: , query: {tokens: {logintoken: 39178f28477fe0aa7a50e1dc4ec566195fd887aa+\}}} I can print token as 39178f28477fe0aa7a50e1dc4ec566195fd887aa+\

Comment: have you tested it in PostMan?

Comment: The api worked so I tried a custom Requests library instead of standart request (https://github.com/jossef/requests). I suppose it is something to do with standart .Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.For future reference, I have downloaded dio package and added intercepter and cookie manager in order to persist the cookies.